# check if div contain a div based on id

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a li tag which was dynamically added. To that based on some condition i added a div with 4 child div to it. After adding all these dynamically my html design was like this

```
<ul>
    <li id="liTab1">
        <div id="TaskDetails">
           <div id="div1"></div>
           <div id="div2"></div>
           <div id="div3"></div>
           <div id="div4"></div>
       </div>
   </li>
```

Now i wanted to remove the div2 and rebind it dynamically at 2nd position only...
is this possible, if so some sample code would be helpfull

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: could you give us your intended html output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there has to be a logical flow for achieve this.

What i would suggest here in this scenario is?

**Scenario 1:**

I would first remove all html from my li and rebind it with updated html as i have all the data with me.

**Scenario 2:** 
I would find the second div using jQuery and change the html of it.

[JQuery HTML](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will help you in changing and removing the HTML of any element.

Comment: if i reload the whole html then the elements in div1 and div2 will be reset before saving

Comment: saving?? what is your functionality.. and you can also try scenario 2.